# What does the letter 'e' means inside a SVG path?

Tags: svg, inkscape

By [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) and [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp) the only letters (commands) avaible in SVG paths are: M/m(moveto), L/z(lineto), H/h(horizontal lineto), V/v(vertical lineto), C/c(curveto), S/s(smooth curveto), Q/q(quadratic Bézier curve), T/t(smooth quadratic Bézier curveto), A/a(elliptical Arc) and Z/z(closepath).

But I just found 'e' (`2.52e-4,1.13167`) on my SVG file made on Inkscape and I need to know what does it means. The complete path:

```
<path style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:0.25446901"
       d="m 83.846207,283.12668 c 15.992614,-15.1728 -2.513154,-76.38272 -19.662265,-19.85549 -2.686628,2.07836 -3.844405,3.79032 -3.843936,5.68391 2.52e-4,1.13167 1.271934,3.67458 2.424778,4.8488 29.290043,-6.79271 2.902502,8.1524 11.570816,9.81493 1.988533,0.34976 6.85716,0.0978 9.510607,-0.49215 z"
       id="path47"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccc" />
```

*ps: the code is result of a 'trace bitmap' made on Inkscape*

Comment: e just means 10^, so 2.52e-4 is another way of writing 2.52*10^4, which is the same as 0.000252. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The e is for exponential notation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

2.52e-4 for example means 0.000252 = 2.52 * 10 ^ -4 = 2.52 * 0.0001